# Geth message: Regenerated Local Transaction Journal

Tags: go-ethereum

When I'm running geth to sync the blockchain, sometimes the message **"Regenerated local transaction journal"** appears, what does it means?

Answer (score 4):

It's just a transaction journal rotation, it's kind of [`log rotation`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_rotation), you can ignore it.

Comment: but it makes sync operation stuck